# Redirect https to http on non secure magento pages

Tags: magento

Magento has some great built in functionality that if you request a page that should be secure e.g. the checkout via http then it redirects to https. However what seems to be lacking is if somebody requests a page that doesn't need to be secure e.g. a category page via https then there does not seem to be the functionality to redirect them to http.

So if somebody requests:

> https://www.mysite.com/mycategory

they get 301 redirected to

> http://www.mysite.com/mycategory

Anybody managed to achieve this?

If not then anybody able to point me in the direction of the bit of the magento core code that does the redirect to HTTPS and then I should be able to work from that to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the following method

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php::_checkShouldBeSecure()
```

Comment: Cheers rich just found that.

Answer (score 6):

So thanks to Rich i tracked this down in app/code/core/Mage/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php::_checkShouldBeSecure()

I amended this function (created copy in app/code/local add amended it there) adding in the **elseif** part

```
protected function _checkShouldBeSecure($request, $path='')
{
    if (!Mage::isInstalled() || $request->getPost()) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->_shouldBeSecure($path) && !Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()) {
        $url = $this->_getCurrentSecureUrl($request);

        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect($url)
            ->sendResponse();
        exit;
    } elseif (!$this->_shouldBeSecure($path) && Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()) {
        $url = $this->_getCurrentUnsecureUrl($request);

        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect($url)
            ->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }
}
```

then added this function

```
protected function _getCurrentUnsecureUrl($request)
{
    if ($alias = $request->getAlias(Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS)) {
        return Mage::getBaseUrl('link', false).ltrim($alias, '/');
    }

    return Mage::getBaseUrl('link', false).ltrim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks so much for the hint above. I integrated the code in a "Magento-like-module" without overloading the Core.

There are only three files to create:

```
app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/config.xml
app/etc/modules/MyCompany_MyModule.xml
```

In `app/etc/modules/MyCompany_MyModule.xml` paste the following uninteresting stuff:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

In `app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/config.xml` paste the Router-Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <default>
        <web>
            <routers>
                <standard>
                    <area>frontend</area>
                    <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard</class>
                </standard>
            </routers>
        </web>
    </default>
</config>
```

And in `app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php` implement the logic from above:

```
<?php

class MyCompany_MyModule_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard {

    protected function _checkShouldBeSecure($request, $path='') {
       parent::_checkShouldBeSecure($request, $path);

       if (!$this->_shouldBeSecure($path) && Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()) {
            $url = $this->_getCurrentUnsecureUrl($request);

            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect($url)
            ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }

    protected function _getCurrentUnsecureUrl($request) {
        if ($alias = $request->getAlias(Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS)) {
            return Mage::getBaseUrl('link', false).ltrim($alias, '/');
        }

        return Mage::getBaseUrl('link', false).ltrim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there was no event to observe which fixed the problem... But overriding the Router is better (for updates) than (technically) replacing.

Answer (score 1):

For additional knowledge please go through following

Check how to resolve issue of custom module frontend url is forced to https. instead of http. If you have used module creator to create module. Than you will definetly find below code in config.xml

```
<admin>
       <routers>
         <[ModuleName]>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>[NameSpace_ModuleName]</module>
                <frontName>[frontName]</frontName>
            </args>
        </[ModuleName]>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

To resolve issue of redirection to https instead of http, you need to comment above code from module config.xml file Path: app/code/(codepool)/(NameSpace)/(ModuleName)/etc/config.xml OR you can add different “frontName” for  and  routers. Eg.:

```
<admin>
       <routers>
         <[ModuleName]>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>[NameSpace_ModuleName]</module>
                <frontName>[frontName]</frontName>
            </args>
        </[ModuleName]>
    </routers>
</admin>

<frontend>
       <routers>
         <[ModuleName]>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>[NameSpace_ModuleName]</module>
                <frontName>[frontName1]</frontName>
            </args>
        </[ModuleName]>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

As per above code admin url will be http://yourdomain.com/index.php/frontName/adminhtml_moduleName/ and  frontend url will be like: http://yourdomain.com/index.php/frontName1

I hope above content is useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

The code above strips the query string from the request, both functions should be changed to add it to the request before the redirect.

See below:

```
$querystring = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

return Mage::getBaseUrl('link', false).ltrim($request->getPathInfo(), '/').($querystring ? '?'.$querystring : '');
```